# Git autocomplete for custom bash functions

Tags: git, bash, bash-completion

In my `.bash_profile`, I have a lot of functional shortcuts for git. For example:

```
function gitpull() {
    branch="$1"

    if [[ -z $branch ]]; then
        current_branch=`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`
        git pull origin $current_branch;
    elif [[ -n $branch && $branch == "m" ]]; then
        git pull origin master;
    else
        git pull origin $branch;
    fi;
}
```

However, when I'm typing this in the terminal, I want it to autocomplete git branches. How do I do this? (I already am using `.git-completion.bash`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Manually-crafted bash completion is as simple as this:

```
# our handler that returns choices by populating Bash array COMPREPLY
# (filtered by the currently entered word ($2) via compgen builtin)
_gitpull_complete() {
    branches=$(git branch -l | cut -c3-)
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$branches" -- "$2"))
}

# we now register our handler to provide completion hints for the "gitpull" command
complete -F _gitpull_complete gitpull
```

After sourcing the above commands:

```
$ gitpull <TAB>
asd     master  qwe     zxc
$ gitpull m<TAB>
$ gitpull master
```

The ultimate reference on bash completion is (of course) the section on [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) in the bash manual, but a nice introduction is given on "Debian Administration" page ([part 1](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) and a more important [part 2](https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)).

Comment: but that doesn't autocomplete it. If I type `gitpull mas<TAB>` it doesn't complete to `master` like it should.

Comment: You're right, sorry, we need to filter the choices with the `compgen` according to the current (prefix) word.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: What about remote branches? If I do `git pull origin <TAB><TAB>` it shows all possible branches (remote and local). Your solution only handles local branches.

Comment: You can add `-a` to `git branch -l` to also list remote branches. However, in that case, you'll probably need to filter names a little bit differently then just with `cut` (you might get `-> local/branch`, etc.)

Comment: Is there a good resource on how to write our own completion? You're right. All of the remote branches look something like `remotes/origin/branchname`. So, I need to get rid of the `remotes/`.

Comment: I've added some refs to my answer. Be sure to check that intro (part 2). It may be a bit dated, but it's still valid.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended method is by using `__git_complete()`:

```
__git_complete gitpull _git_pull
```

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the bash completion (in `contrib/`) is updated to make it easier for end-users to add completion for their custom "`git`" subcommands.

Thank to [FelipeC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10474/felipec) (who wrote a [previous answer on that same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56757738/6309))

See [commit 5a067ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a067ba9d04eebc92ad77f101b785219238f4f1e), [commit 0e02bdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e02bdc17a4d4beca06d5606a1d3020c79676d7f), [commit 810df0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/810df0ea8ed00f31d372f3fd90c205d953aea1e6), [commit 7f94b78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f94b78ddabdb49cde32b088ca66b422e7cda628) (30 Dec 2020) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f9fb906](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9fb9063fd792e3f50ae2cd0847c88d2df287068), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a067ba9d04eebc92ad77f101b785219238f4f1e): add proper public __git_complete
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> When `__git_complete` was introduced, it was meant to be temporarily, while a proper guideline for public shell functions was established (tentatively `_GIT_complete`), but since that never happened, people in the wild started to use `__git_complete`, even though it was marked as not public.
>
> Eight years is more than enough wait, let's mark this function as public, and make it a bit more user-friendly.
>
> So that instead of doing:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gk __gitk_main
> ```
>
> The user can do:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gk gitk
> ```
>
> And instead of:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gf _git_fetch
> ```
>
> Do:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gf git_fetch
> ```
>
> Backwards compatibility is maintained.